# How to flash AMD BIOS chip on automated catheter production machine in factory?

Tags: bios, flashing

This is my first question I hope I make it clear enough and posted in the right section.

The automated catheter production machine at the factory I'm doing my internship is down. When turned on there is no response and the front console shows esMINT v2.67j/5/x/m.

It turns out that this is what is written on the sticker of the BIOS chip. After removing the sticker I found the name of the BIOS chip as: AM27512-70DC also was written 0021D5AT (copyright sign) 1986 AMD Malaysia.

I am pretty sure this does not come from the CMOS (rechargeable) as the voltmeter reading is showing 2.19/2.3v for a 2.4v.

What we were thinking is that the BIOS chip needs to be flashed on the board itself because the technician thinks the BIOS got erased when the CMOS got discharged after a long period of inactivity. I'm not sure that if I remove the chip and use a programmer to flash, it would work as the senior technician thinks that the chip being an EPROM, all the BIOS would get erased when removed from the programmer before even getting back on the mainboard.

I also can't Hotboot as this machine is the only one in the factory.

I am a bit confused about all this and would like to get some advice on how to get this machine back on the production line.

Comment: Only the code in the BIOS chip itself would know which version it is. I'd guess that the BIOS code actually just prints its own version number, and then hangs later, due to some other reason. Either replace this machine with the backup machine, or pay its manufacturer's support to do this.

Comment: 27xxx EPROMs do not lose their data when power is removed.

Comment: The AM27512 is a UV erasable PROM, so it can only be erased by removing it from the board and putting it in a UV eraser. It is very unlikely that it has somehow become erased. I doubt that is where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
CL, the replacement machine is already running. I tried to contact the manufacturer but the contact email returns a failed postmaster delivery status. The facility is in Tunisia, so its quite difficult to get my hands on something or someone official as the manufacturer is in the USA.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio and Steve, Just in case, what should I do if if by chance, or lack of it if you want, the chips had been exposed to UV light? I noticed a corner of the sticker sealing the window was not stuck properly which could indicate prior fiddling?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the "BIOS" consists of *two* distinct parts.

One is the (P)ROM which contains the BIOS's program code. This memory will keep its content whether power is supplied or not, for decades.

Then there's the configuration data for the BIOS which is normally stored in a battery-backed RAM and can be modified via some BIOS user interface. This configuration data may get lost when the battery fails or is removed. However, this should cause the BIOS to adopt safe default values to at least enable the user to enter the BIOS UI to set up a new configuration as desired.

So, a failure of the BIOS's code memory is unlikely, though not impossible after thrity(!) years. Failure of the battery or power supply for the RAM is possible but that should not lock you out of the machine completely.

As @SteveG noted, the problem can basically be anywhere in the machine (almost 30 years? Really?) and is probably not in the BIOS.

(I'm not going to point out the implications of having decades-old machines in critical functions without having a backup system in place...)

Comment: Thank you Jimmy,
I will try to look around a bit more. If I understood properly, its that even a new battery wouldn't help?
The techs have already put the replacement machine on  which is more recent. Idon't think the broken down one is that old. What I understood is that  the chip is not the original one as the machine has already failed in the past, and the chip replaced with an older one. I am completely locked out, just have this error message on the console. Also I can see something that could be a VGA connector linked to the mother board; will try to connect through this.

Comment: Also the machine has been running the past years, it had been turned off for just about six months according to the techs

Comment: Took some pics but just realized I cant upload any